# dc.js responsive map and zoom function (mousewheel)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, responsive, dc.js

I have forked the example dc.js (version 4) map file is this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/doyj7h1m/9/). What I want is for the map to be responsive to the Bootstrap container. So, if the screen size changes the map is displayed correctly. The SVG is responsive by setting the width and height to null and a CSS format to set the width and height to 100%. However I see that the underlying `<g>` (layer0) element is not responsive. Therefore I tried to add a scale element to the projection. But unfortunately I don't know how to make it flexible like I did with the SVG element.

In addition, I would like to have the possibility to zoom in. Hopefully someone can help me with this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div id="world-map" class="responsive"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<pre id="data">country  total
      Belgium   2   
      Germany   3   
      France    4   
</pre>
```

```
function world(data) {
  var xf = crossfilter(data);
  var country = xf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.country;
  });
  var countryGroup = country.group().reduceSum(d => +d.total);

  var worldMap = new dc.GeoChoroplethChart("#world-map");
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json").then(function(worldJson) {
    worldMap
      .width(null)
      .height(null)
      .dimension(country)
      .group(countryGroup)
      .colors(d3.scaleQuantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
      .colorDomain([0, 200])
      .colorCalculator(function(d) {
      return d ? worldMap.colors()(d) : '#ccc';
    })
      .overlayGeoJson(worldJson.features, "state", function(d) {
      return d.properties.name;
    })
      .projection(d3.geoEquirectangular()
                  .scale(100)
                  .translate([800 / 2, 400 / 2])
                 )
      .valueAccessor(function(kv) {
      //console.log(kv);
      return kv.value;
    })
      .title(function(d) {
      return d.key + "\nTotal: " + (d.value ? d.value : 0);
    });

    dc.renderAll();

  });
}

const data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select('pre#data').text());

world(data);
```

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

pre#data {
  display: none;
}

.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's not my favorite solution because text can get distorted, but did you try [useViewBoxResizing](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#useViewBoxResizing__anchor)? Otherwise, there is a [folder of resizing examples](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/resizing/) which might help. The tough part is detecting when a div has changed size - sadly there is still no cross-browser method in 2020.

Comment: Hi Gordon, i found a solution to make the layer0 responsive by setting a variable innerWidth and innerHeight to the bootstrap container and replaced the translate (800 and 400) with these variables. But do you also know a solution to zoom in on the chart?

Comment: Are you asking about [mouseZoomable](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CoordinateGridMixin.html#mouseZoomable__anchor) or something else?

Comment: Yes do you know how to apply the mouseZoomable to this map?

Comment: Oh I forgot this was the geo-choropleth. Hmm, it’s not built-in, it might not be all that difficult but I’m not sure if I’ll have time in the next few days. Now I see that you asked two questions in one, clever trick.

Comment: Yes never betting on one horse :) But for the first question i found a solution.

Comment: Hi Gordon, you found some spare time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to connect [d3-zoom](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom) to change the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) of a parent `<g>` in response to zoom events.

First, pull out the projection initialization because we'll need the initial values later:

```
  const scale0 = 100, x0 = 800 / 2, y0 = 400 / 2, 
    projection = d3.geoEquirectangular()
      .scale(scale0)
      .translate([x0, y0])
  worldMap
    .projection(projection)
```

Then add the zoom handlers after the chart renders:

```
  worldMap.on('postRender', chart => {
    const zoom = d3.zoom();
    zoom.on('zoom', () => {
      const {k, x, y} = d3.event.transform;
      chart.select('g.layer0')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${x},${y}) scale(${k})`)
    })
    chart.svg().call(zoom);
  });
```

Each time we receive a zoom event, we'll pull the scale, x and y offset from the event, and apply them to a transform that looks like

```
translate(-350.6778787924404,-173.42665430196223) scale(1.9132163161837539)
```

On my first try, I applied a new projection and redrew the chart. This worked but it had performance problems. Changing the transform is the way to go!

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/p2z7j6wr/5/), with pan and zoom.

Comment: Thanks again Gordon, i am just starting with dc and d3 so for me everything is new. I am wondering if you also have something like a min and max that you can set on the zooming. Now you can zoom so far out that the map disappears.

Comment: This stuff isn’t from dc.js; it’s all standard D3 stuff. Please take a look at [zoom.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_extent) and the next couple of functions in the d3-zoom documentation. I think it is what you are looking for.