# Zooming on a GeoChoroplethChart in an Angular project

Tags: angular, dc.js

I'm having trouble in understanding how zooming works for a GeoChoroplethChart. As per documentation, zoom is implemented in CoordinateGridMixin which GeoChoroplethChart does not inherit from. Moreover, the typescript types (index.d.ts file) do not refer to such function.

Should be mentioned that the implementation I made is for the world map, not US only which doesn't really need zooming.

The expected behavior is to be able to zoom-in (by scroll-up) the area around the mouse pointer and vice-versa.

Does anyone have any idea how this should be solved? Thanks

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions about the charting library. [dc] is a venerable Unix “desktop calculator”. Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60920890/676195

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @[Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676195/gordon) for guiding me to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60920890/676195)! I have put this issue on the back burner lately, but I see that it works just fine, after a brief testing.